# Running a specific macro on all sheets besides named ones in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which calls other macros to run on specified sheets.

Firstly: I was wondering how to tell it to run another macro on all remaining sheets that haven't been previously listed

Secondly: I want the above macro to run on the remaining sheets excluding a number of named sheets (e.g. "graphs")

Here is my code so far

```
Sub specify_sheets()

'apply appropriate limits to relative sheet

Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In Worksheets
    If sht.Name = Worksheets("NB12") Or _
       sht.Name = Worksheets("NB15") Then
        Call limits_Alluvium
    End If

    If sht.Name = Worksheets("NB24") Then
        Call limits_BOCOBOML_GFA

    End If

    If sht.Name = Worksheets("NB16") Or _
       sht.Name = Worksheets("NB17") Or _
        sht.Name = Worksheets("NB19") Or _
        sht.Name = Worksheets("NB20") Or _
       sht.Name = Worksheets("Bore 31") Then
       Call limits_BOCOBOML_MIA

    End If

    If sht.Name = Worksheets("Bore 47") Or _
       sht.Name = Worksheets("Bore 48") Then
       Call limits_FracturedRock_GFA

    End If

        If sht.Name = Worksheets("Bore 4") Or _
       sht.Name = Worksheets("Bore 4a") Or _
        sht.Name = Worksheets("Bore 40") Then
       Call limits_FracturedRock_MIA_West

    End If

        If sht.Name = Worksheets("Bore 30") Then
       Call limits_FracturedRock_MIA_East

    End If

Next sht


End Sub
```

Here is the code from one of the macros it calls on:

```
Sub limits_Monitoring_bores()

        Dim sht As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
        Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet

'Name columns appropriately


 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Min"
    .Cells(1, 5).Value = "Max"
    .Cells(1, 7).Value = "20th Percentile"
    .Cells(1, 8).Value = "80th Percentile"
    .Cells(1, 10).Value = "20th Percentile"
    .Cells(1, 11).Value = "80th Percentile"

End With

        lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        sh.Range("D2:D" & lastRow).Value = "=6"
        sh.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Value = "=8.5"
        sh.Range("G2:G" & lastRow).Value = "=PERCENTILE(F:F,0.2)"
        sh.Range("H2:H" & lastRow).Value = "=PERCENTILE(F:F,0.8)"
        sh.Range("J2:J" & lastRow).Value = "=PERCENTILE(I:I,0.2)"
        sh.Range("K2:K" & lastRow).Value = "=PERCENTILE(I:I,0.8)"

End Sub
```

Comment: I have this ```If sht.Name <> "EA Graphs" And sht.Name <> "Graphs" Then
            Call limits_Monitoring_bores
        End If``` but I dont want it to run on the bores I've already listed in my original question. Is there an easier way or do I just list them using this code here

Comment: How does your called code (eg "limits_Alluvium") know which sheet it's supposed to operate on?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:-

```
Sub STO()

    Dim Fun As String    
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    For Each Sht In Worksheets
        Select Case Sht.Name
            Case "NB12", "NB15"
                limits_Alluvium
            Case "NB24"
                limits_BOCOBOML_GFA
            Case "NB16", "NB17", "NB19", "NB20", "Bore 31"
                limits_BOCOBOML_MIA
            Case "Bore 47", "Bore 48"
                limits_FracturedRock_GFA
            Case "Bore 4", "Bore 4a", "Bore 40"
                limits_FracturedRock_MIA_West
            Case "Bore 30"
                limits_FracturedRock_MIA_East
            Case Else
                If Len(Fun) Then Fun = Fun & vbCr
                Fun = Fun & Sht.Name
        End Select
    Next Sht
    MsgBox Fun, vbInformation, "Sheets not processed"
End Sub
```

Sheets not listed anywhere will not be processed.

Comment: Better than my answer.  Add a `Case Else` to process any other sheets not listed in the specific cases.

Comment: Thanks for the ```Case Else``` If there's sheets I don't want to run would I just run a Case with each one listed and do something or?

Comment: Hi this only seemed to run on the first worksheet but none of the others

Comment: I've added some code from one of the macros it calls it. I think it may need adjusting?

Comment: My code - in fact, **your** code - loops through all the sheets. All of them, not just one. It looks at every name. If the name is listed in any of the 'Cases' it will run that particular macro. I don't think a 'Case Else' is an improvement but you can use it for testing. I have modified my code to include such a test. It will issue a MsgBox with a list of all worksheets which aren't listed. Look for blank spaces in your worksheet names. After it's done its job remove the extra code.

Comment: my other macros that I wanted to use in this weren't compatible - I kept getting errors. So i went with a method I'll post as an answer