# Issues using "Case" in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which applies other macros to specific sheets depending on their name:

```
Sub Specify()

    Dim Fun As String
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    For Each Sht In Worksheets
        Select Case Sht.Name
            Case "NB12", "NB15"
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_Alluvium"
            Case "NB24"
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_BOCOBOML_GFA"
            Case "NB16", "NB17", "NB19", "NB20", "Bore 31"
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_BOCOBOML_MIA"
            Case "Bore 47", "Bore 48"
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_FracturedRock_GFA"
            Case "Bore 4", "Bore 4a", "Bore 40"
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_FracturedRock_MIA_West"
            Case "Bore 30"
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_FracturedRock_MIA_East"
            Case Else
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_Monitoring_bores"

        End Select
    Next Sht

End Sub
```

I was having an issue where every sheet, no matter the name, would get

```
Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_Monitoring_bores"
```

applied to it. When troubleshooting, I found that when no macro was associated with 
`Case Else`
the correct macro would be applied to the given sheet. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Check your sheet name, maybe any space there, check with debug.print sht.name

Comment: You might want to finish up with loose ends first, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59816249/9758194). There is too little information here to reproduce what you are experiencing.

Comment: `I found that when no macro was associated with Case Else the correct macro would be applied to the given sheet` - no, that doesn't happen. Introduction of a `Case Else` does not steal a match from other `Case`s, and removal of `Case Else` does not return a match to the other `Case`s.

Comment: Checked the sheet name for spaces etc. @user11982798

Comment: Well after troubleshooting that seems to be what is happening, is there some sort of order? like does ```Case else``` take priority over other cases? @GSerg

Comment: case else will happen after all case before case else not found

Comment: I think this happened because when you call For Each Sht In Worksheets, last sheet is not as monitored case, please check with debug.pint Sht.Name in case else

Comment: @user11982798 do I run debug.print sht.name under ```Case Else``` alone? or with ```Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_Monitoring_bores"```?

Comment: did both and ```debug.print Sht.Name``` returned nothing

Comment: it's strange, wether it's alone or with other line, it will give the name of sheet